# How can I create a healthy and balanced vegetarian diet?

Tags: nutrition

When going vegetarian, there is a problem; where can one get the protein he/she used to get from meat?

How can one create a healthy and balanced vegetarian diet, so as to get the proper nutrition people get when they eat meat, which eating it?

Comment: Don't feel bad that this is a duplicate. I wouldn't have found it based on the other title, so at least this will serve as a signpost for others!

Comment: @Tim - Actually, this really isn't a duplicate. Yes, some of the information there is extremely relevant, but we would need to know what *kind* of vegetarian diet. In the duplicate case, it's lacto-ovo which can include eggs and dairy, so the concern for complete proteins is less. If this is a strict vegetarian/vegan diet, there are different considerations for both proteins and vitamins/minerals.

Comment: @Tim - Then it should have been asked for clarification in the comments as to what type of diet they were specifying, not an automatic duplicate close vote. Just because the other question happened to (luckily) answer what they needed, doesn't mean that that one answer is going to be a blanket address for every vegetarian diet question.